# Without Login page, home page is coming up

Tags: community, customer-community

I have setup a Community and designed custom Login page and home page. I have used both custom pages and try to launch the URL, the URL is directly taking me to the Home page without login page.

Login page settings:
[image]

Home page setings:
[image]

Site settings:

[image]

[image]
Regards,
Ajay

Comment: which profile is it logged in under?

Comment: there is no login page to login, it is directly taking me to the landing page. I have the member under custom community profile

Comment: @tuskiomi: added the settings screenshot for your reference in case.

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code for the login page as well?

Comment: Where are you launching the community from, the URL or by logging in to a community user?

Comment: @DaveHumm: using the URL. if I remove the home page VF page and select the default page, then it will take me to the login page.

Comment: Just to be sure that you don't have an access token already existing in your browser, navigate to the community URL in a private/anonymous browser window.

Comment: @JohnThompson: I have used a different laptop:). Still the result is same. I am pretty much sure I am doing a silly mistake.

Comment: @Ajay in your site's which every community has what's the home page ?select login page on sites .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava: I dont find the place to put Login page on Site. Added screenshots

Comment: Active Home page is the one . Whatever you have there will display if guest users can access

Comment: how do I enforce login page and upon authentication success, land the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check your visibility options in the "Community Builder" to make sure that your community isn't exposed to the public?

1) Login to the Community Builder
2) Click on Settings > General
3) Make sure that "Public Access" is unchecked

Next, check the visibility settings on your page variations

4) Click on "Page Manager"
5) Click on Home
6) Select "Page Variations" and check what the visibility is set to - you can modify the visibility options from the checkbox on the far right-hand side.